# Error: Main method not found in class, please define the main method as:public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java, javafx

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста упражнения с книги headfirs java почему код не запускается ?

```
public class GuessGame {
        Player p1;
        Player p2;
        Player p3;

        public void startGame () {
            p1 = new Player();
            p2 = new Player();
            p3 = new Player();
            int guessp1 = 0;
            int guessp2 = 0;
            int guessp3 = 0;

            boolean p1isRight = false;
            boolean p2isRight = false;
            boolean p3isRight = false;

            int targetNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            System.out.println("Я загадываю желания");

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Число,которое нужно угадать, - " + targetNumber);
                p1.guess();
                p2.guess();
                p3.guess();

                guessp1 = p1.number;
                System.out.println("Первый игрок думает что это " + guessp1);
                guessp2 = p2.number;
                System.out.println("Первый игрок думает что это " + guessp1);
                guessp3 = p3.number;
                System.out.println("Первый игрок думает что это " + guessp1);

                if (guessp1 == targetNumber) {
                    p1isRight = true;
                }
                if (guessp2 == targetNumber) {
                    p2isRight = true;
                }
                if (guessp3 == targetNumber) {
                    p3isRight = true;
                }

                if (p1isRight || p2isRight || p3isRight) {
                    System.out.println(" У нас есть первый победитель!");
                    System.out.println("Первый игрок угадал?" + p1isRight);
                    System.out.println("Второй игрок угадал? " + p2isRight);
                    System.out.println("Третий игрок угадал? " + p3isRight);
                    System.out.println("Конец Игры");
                    break;
                }
                 else {
                    System.out.println("Игроки должны попробывать еще раз.");
                }

        }
    }
```

Пишет ошибку:

```
Error: Main method not found in class GuessGame, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Comment: В тексте ошибки всё написано.

Comment: я добавляю внутри `public class GuessGame` `public static void main(String[] args)` но выходит та же ошибка

Comment: Значит не туда. Или не так.

Comment: Вы в конфигурациях запуска приложения указали главный метод после того, как добавили его в тело класса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
public class GuessGame {
    Player p1;
    Player p2;
    Player p3;

    public static void main(String[]args){
       new GuessGame().startGame();
    }

    public void startGame () {
        p1 = new Player();
        p2 = new Player();
        p3 = new Player();
        int guessp1 = 0;
        int guessp2 = 0;
        int guessp3 = 0;

        boolean p1isRight = false;
        boolean p2isRight = false;
        boolean p3isRight = false;

        int targetNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println("Я загадываю желания");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Число,которое нужно угадать, - " + targetNumber);
            p1.guess();
            p2.guess();
            p3.guess();

            guessp1 = p1.number;
            System.out.println("Первый игрок думает что это " + guessp1);
            guessp2 = p2.number;
            System.out.println("Первый игрок думает что это " + guessp1);
            guessp3 = p3.number;
            System.out.println("Первый игрок думает что это " + guessp1);

            if (guessp1 == targetNumber) {
                p1isRight = true;
            }
            if (guessp2 == targetNumber) {
                p2isRight = true;
            }
            if (guessp3 == targetNumber) {
                p3isRight = true;
            }

            if (p1isRight || p2isRight || p3isRight) {
                System.out.println(" У нас есть первый победитель!");
                System.out.println("Первый игрок угадал?" + p1isRight);
                System.out.println("Второй игрок угадал? " + p2isRight);
                System.out.println("Третий игрок угадал? " + p3isRight);
                System.out.println("Конец Игры");
                break;
            }
             else {
                System.out.println("Игроки должны попробывать еще раз.");
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Отлично спасибо вам большое